# Tabla nueva a partir de un JOIN, e incluir TODOS los valores

Tags: mysql

estoy cruzando 2 tablas, las cuales tienen diferentes cantidades de registros.
El tema es que la tabla 1, tiene 160 registros, y la tabla 2 tiene 88 registros.
Por lo que mi consulta actual, solo trae los que logra encontrar, los cuales son solamente 85 de ellos.

¿Cómo debería hacer el JOIN para que incluya todos?
Es decir, los faltantes de la tabla 1 y la tabla 2 ???

```
CREATE TABLE certificado3
SELECT 
c.rut_empresa as rut_empresa,
c2.rut_empresa as rut_empresa2
FROM certificado c
JOIN certificado2 c2 on c.rut_empresa = c2.rut_empresa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo, aunque no lo indiques, es un `inner join` que únicamente trae las filas de las tablas en la que coincide el `rut_empresa`. Para traer todas las filas de las dos tablas deberías hacer un `full join` que hasta dónde sé, no existe en `mysql` pero puedes emularlo de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT c.rut_empresa as rut_empresa,
       c2.rut_empresa as rut_empresa2
       FROM certificado c
       LEFT JOIN certificado2 c2 
            on c.rut_empresa = c2.rut_empresa

UNION

SELECT c.rut_empresa as rut_empresa,
       c2.rut_empresa as rut_empresa2
       FROM certificado c
       RIGHT JOIN certificado2 c2 
            on c.rut_empresa = c2.rut_empresa
```

Con el `LEFT JOIN` te aseguras todas las filas de `certificado` y con el `RIGHT JOIN` las de `certificado2`, la coincidentes se duplican en las dos consultas pero el `UNION` además de unir las dos columnas elimina esta duplicdad.