# MYSQL - No se logra la exportación excel de una consulta hecha con UNION

Tags: mysql, excel

Por alguna razón que no entiendo, no puedo realizar la exportación de una consulta hecha con UNION.

Esta consulta es una que me dieron en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/483518/131662

Al momento de ejecutarla en PHPMYADMIN, funciona perfecto.
Al momento de exportarla a EXCEL, esto es lo que arroja.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo entiendo que esa columna no existe. En la respuesta enlazada esa columna está renombrada como `c.rut_empresa`. Creo que van por ahí los tiros

Comment: Independiente, la consulta hecha en MYSQL no es erronea, devuelve los datos. El problema está en exportar esos datos.

Comment: Al final de tú imagen dice "La columna 'certificado.rut_empresa' en field list es desconocida", yo creo que por ahí va la cosa, si la consulta no esta bien, no te retornara datos.

Comment: Que si retorna datos XDDDD

Comment: ¿Cómo la estás llamando desde Excel?

Comment: @Esei No entiendo esa pregunta... Como llamando de excel ?

Comment: ¿Desde donde ejecutas la exportación a Excel? ¿has probado a conectar desde Excel con la base y entonces traerte la consulta?

Comment: phpmyadmin lo dije antes